# Update Android Things app via USB and package installer

Tags: android, permissions, android-things

Due to the shutdown of Android Things console in 2022 I would like to know if someone of you tried to update the app via USB.

I tried with no success:

First try:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", layoutPath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Result:
Package installer cannot install the app due to MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES. I cannot modify that flag in MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES.

Second try:

```
Log.e(TAG,layoutPath.getPath());
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + layoutPath.getPath());
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install -r " + layoutPath.getPath());
```

Result:

```
Permission Denial: runInstallCreate from pm command asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

Do you have better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can install or update apps on your device manually using the [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) (adb). Versions of your app installed using this method will override any existing version bundled into the factory image so long as you have specified a [higher version](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning).

For more details on connecting to your specific device with ADB, see the [hardware guides](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a good way of updating the app but not feasible if the device is already on the market worldwide.

Comment: Probably is better using the following command in the setup process: adb shell appops set <mypackage> REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES allow